# How to set different values in the same reference

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have a three classes `TestDTO`, `TestImpl` and `TestMain`. `TestDTO` has amount variable , setter and getter methods. `TestImpl` has methods like `getTestDTO()` and `getUpdatedTestDTO()`.

I have created a `testdto` object and set amount value as `05`. this `testdto` has stored the `testDTO` ArrayList object. Here in `TestImpl` I have two setter and getter for `userTest` and `currentTest`. I have set `testDTO` ArrayList object to `setUserTest` and `setCurrentTest`. when I try to print the amount value from `userTest` and `currentTest` I got the 5 as an Output.

I injected like `getUserTest().get(0).setAmount("06");` then when I try to print `currentTest.getAmount()` it prints `06` rather than `05`

TestDTO:

```
public class TestDTO{
   private String amount;
   public void setAmount(String amount) {
      this.amount = amount;
   }
   public String getAmount() {
      return amount;
   }
}
```

TestImpl:

```
public class TestImpl {
   private ArrayList<TestDTO> userTest;
   private ArrayList<TestDTO> currentTest;

   public ArrayList<TestDTO> getTestDTO(){
      ArrayList<TestDTO> testDTO = new ArrayList<TestDTO>();
      TestDTO testdto = new TestDTO();
      testdto.setAmount("05");
      testDTO.add(testdto);
      this.setUserTest(testDTO);
      this.setCurrentTest(testDTO);
      return null;
   }
   public void getUpdateTestDTO() {
      System.out.println(this.userTest.get(0).getAmount());
      System.out.println(this.currentTest.get(0).getAmount());
   }
   public ArrayList<TestDTO> getUserTest(){
      return userTest;
   }
   public void setUserTest(ArrayList<TestDTO> userTest) {
      this.userTest = userTest;
   }
   public ArrayList<TestDTO> getCurrentTest(){
      return currentTest;
   }
   public void setCurrentTest(ArrayList<TestDTO> currentTest) {
      this.currentTest = currentTest;
   }
}
```

TestMain:

```
public class TestMain {
   TestImpl testImpl = new TestImpl();

   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      TestMain testMain = new TestMain();
      testMain.testImpl.getTestDTO();
      testMain.testImpl.getUpdateTestDTO();
      testMain.testImpl.getUserTest().get(0).setAmount("06");
      testMain.testImpl.getUpdateTestDTO();
   }
}
```

I expect `userTest.getAmount()` return `06` and `currentTest.getAmount()` return `05`.

Comment: Both userTest arraylist and currentTest store the reference that points to same object. This is why change in one is only reflected in other. You need to do a deep copy of object to make sure that they are separate.

Comment: Also what the heck are you doing in main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in both ArrayList userTest and currentTest. You have an Arraylist that stores reference that points towards same object.

```
currentTest ---> testDTOArrayList@ioaudo
userTest ---->   testDTOArrayList@ioaudo

testDTOArrayList@ioaudo --> testDTOArrayList
testDTOArrayList ---> testdto@oisudf

testdto@oisudf ---> ---------------
                    | amount = 05 |
                    ---------------
```

So we compiler runs line

```
testImpl.getUserTest().get(0).setAmount("06");
```

The change is reflected in `currentTest` as well because they point towards same thing.

To avoid that you need to have separate array list so change in one isn't reflected in other.

```
// This function will copy all values from one object and create a new object
// Stored copied values in it put in array list and return that arraylist 
public ArrayList<TestDTO> deepCopy(TestDTO testdto) {
   TestDTO testdtoCopy = new TestDTO();
   testdtoCopy.setAmount(testdto.getAmount());
   ArrayList<TestDTO> testDTOCopyArrayList = new ArrayList<TestDTO>();
   testDTOCopyArrayList.add(testdtoCopy);
   return testDTOCopy;
}
```

Your getTestDTO would be

```
public ArrayList<TestDTO> getTestDTO() {
   ArrayList<TestDTO> testDTOArrayList = new ArrayList<TestDTO>();
   TestDTO testdto = new TestDTO();
   testdto.setAmount("05");
   testDTOArrayList.add(testdto);
   this.setUserTest(testDTOArrayList);
   this.setCurrentTest(deepCopy(testdto));
   return testDTOArrayList;
}
```

Now both objects will be separate

```
userTest  ---> testDTOArrayList@ioaudo
currentTest ---->  testDTOCopyArray@weuirwi

testDTOArrayList@ioaudo --> testDTOArrayList
testDTOCopyArray@weuirwi ---> testDTOCopyArray

testDTOArrayList --> testdto@oisudf
testdto@oisudf ---> ---------------
                    | amount = 05 |
                    ---------------

testDTOCopyArray --> testdto@5446dfg
testdto@5446dfg --->  ---------------
                      | amount = 05 |
                      ---------------
```

**Output:**

```
05
05
06
05
```

Comment: Hi @Lenny if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

NO, that is not possible sir. When you are setting the amount it is being set for the same **testDTO** that is why you will always get the same value.

To achieve the result you are expecting, try following solution.

```
    ArrayList<TestDTO> testDTO = new ArrayList<TestDTO>();  
    TestDTO testdto = new TestDTO();
    testdto.setAmount("05");
    testDTO.add(testdto);
    this.setUserTest(testDTO);
    ****ArrayList<TestDTO> testDTO22 = new ArrayList<TestDTO>();  
    ****TestDTO testdto22 = new TestDTO();
    ****testdto22.setAmount("05");
    ****testDTO22.add(testdto);
    ****this.setCurrentTest(testDTO22);
```

Look for star marked lines.

Comment: I am not providing any example here(it is his code, all he is trying in that method is to set value. method name might be confusing). I am trying to solve the problem he is concerned for. Please go through the question once.